# Python kubernetes client to create a K8 Gateway Class

Tags: python, kubernetes, client

Hi I am looking for python kubernetes api class to create a K8 gatewayClass if anyone knows the class please share didnt saw that on their documentation

Comment: You can find it out by checking the API group and the version, check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70026818/2704032

Comment: `kubectl get --raw "/"` this should tell you in which API it belongs to, check if the kubernetes client for python have the client for that or not